# didReceiveRemoteNotification is not running when app is running (FOREGROUND)

Tags: swift, apple-push-notifications, ios9

I have a strange case. My swift ios app is connected to Cloudkit. If the app is NOT running (background state), I receive my notifications badge and alert just fine, every time!
If the app is running, no notifications are received! I know it is not hitting the remote because I do this:
1. Adding a breakpoint to the didReceiveRemoteNotification event
2. Running xcode in a plugged iphone
3. NSLog("detected didReceiveRemoteNotification"), so final code look like this

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]){
  NSLog("detected didReceiveRemoteNotification")
}
```

I know the error is not coming from cloudkit or from APNS because I do receive alert banner and badge when the phone is in the background state.

Can you guide me to set this up properly for the Foreground state!?

I am running ios v9.3

UPDATE #1
I think the wording of the documentation is poor. It clearly says that both run on the foreground, which is what I cared about; nevertheless, the fix is more accurate than the documentation!

> Unlike the application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: method, which is
>   called only when your app is running in the foreground, the system
>   calls this method when your app is running in the foreground or
>   background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've implemented the wrong method. Implement:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
    didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],
    fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
```

As the docs explain:

> Unlike the `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` method, ... the system calls this method when your app is running in the foreground or background.